# Select item in Spinner, parse a XML and pick a value - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, parsing, spinner

I'm going to explain you my problem..

- I have an Android Studio's layout with 2 spinners, both of them have these values: "EUR","USD","GBP","CAD"

  - I'm using this website: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml    to get the currency rate value (taxes)
  - I want to check the selected item of my Spinner (for example, if USD is selected), parse the XML, and pick the rate of the USD..
  - When you parse a XML label and you want to paste the value into a TextView, you can use:

```html
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            progreso.dismiss();
            try{
                Dates dt=parseoXML(s);
                tvTest.setText(tmp.getCiudad()); //tvTest is the TextView
```

How can I do to make something similat wirh a spinner??

I know it's a pretty hard question without pasting all the code (It's a lot of code, classes,etc), but I just want to know your suggestions, ideas, similar examples, etc

Thanks in advance!